# How to change the box into random colors continuously

Tags: javascript, html, css, settimeout, setinterval

I am experimenting with the `setInterval` and `setTimeout` functions by changing the background color of div.

What I am trying to achieve here is I would like the box to change into random colors **continuously**. I also have a function that I can stop the box from changing its color by clicking the box.

```js
var colorChanger = document.getElementById("colour-changer");
var r = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
var g = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
var b = Math.round(Math.random()*255);

function changeColor(){

  colorChanger.style.backgroundColor =  "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";

}

var myTimer = setInterval(changeColor, 3000);
var running = true;

colorChanger.onclick = function(){

  if(running) {
    clearInterval(myTimer);
    colorChanger.innerHTML = "Timer stopped";
    running = false;
  } else {
    myTimer = setInterval(changeColor, 3000);
    colorChanger.innerHTML = "";
    running = true;
  }
 
};
```

```css
#colour-changer {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  margin:30px auto;
  background-color:#fff;

  -webkit-transition:background-color 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.7s;
  transition:background-color 0.7s;
}
```

```html
  <div id="colour-changer"></div>
```

Why isn't this changing the random colors continuously?

Comment: `changeColor` isn't changing the color. You need to move the `random` code *inside* the function, so you'll get a different r, g and b each time.

Comment: You should move color generators into changeColor method.

Comment: Thanks guys. I hate the fact that I think too much to spot such a simple stuff :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to generate the random `rgb`s inside of `changeColor`. Note that you should probably use `Math.floor` rather than `Math.round` for a fair output, and you can make your code DRY-er by calling a function that returns the random number:

```js
var colorChanger = document.getElementById("colour-changer");

const randNum = () => Math.floor(Math.random()*256);

function changeColor(){
  colorChanger.style.backgroundColor =  `rgb(${randNum()},${randNum()},${randNum()})`;
}

var myTimer = setInterval(changeColor, 3000);
var running = true;

colorChanger.onclick = function(){

  if(running) {
    clearInterval(myTimer);
    colorChanger.innerHTML = "Timer stopped";
    running = false;
  } else {
    myTimer = setInterval(changeColor, 3000);
    colorChanger.innerHTML = "";
    running = true;
  }
 
};
```

```css
#colour-changer {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  margin:30px auto;
  background-color:#fff;

  -webkit-transition:background-color 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.7s;
  transition:background-color 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<div id="colour-changer"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much...I guess I still haven't fully understood about the loop statement...I hate the fact that I think too much that I miss such a rookie mistake :(

Comment: Question! = () => and $ (despite you did not use jQuery) I assume these are the latest ES6 stuff?

Comment: `() =>` is an arrow function - concise syntax for a function with implicit return of the following expression when not followed by `{` brackets. The backtick string with `${somevar}` inside is called a template literal, which allows for interpolated variables. Yes, they are ES6 syntax, but it's not exactly the latest - ES6 (aka ES2015) was 3 years ago.

Comment: Wow...I feel like I am missing a lot of stuff. Is learning ES6 kind of like learning jQuery to speed up the workflow? I am feeling overwhelmed as I do not know when I should start learning ES6.

Comment: No, jQuery is not all that important to know nowadays, because standard built-in Javascript can almost always accomplish the same thing without any difficulty. Knowing how the base language works is much more important than figuring out any library (especially if the library is, arguably, somewhat obsolete). But ES6 and other modern language features, being the base language, *are* (and will always be) useful and important to know ASAP.

Comment: Thank you for a great advice. Yes, like any other subjects, basics are important but I see a number of companies looking for people who know -- which means "read" and "write" -- jQuery. When it comes to job hunting, do you think I will have the edge over others for having jQuery on my resume?

Comment: jQuery is frequently used in older codebases. If you apply somewhere that's working on older architecture, jQuery will be helpful to know, but knowing it is much less likely to be useful with recent projects. It's better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

```
 // Generate A Random Color
function randomColor () {
  var red   = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
  var green = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
  var blue  = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)); 
  return 'rgb(' + red + ',' + green + ',' + blue +')';
}

$(document).ready(function () {
   setInterval(function() {
     var color = randomColor();
     $('body').css('background-color', color);
   }, 4000); // end of setInterval 
}
```

P.S: Please note I am using jQuery for the demonstration purpose.

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask two questions? Why did you return below variables and Why did you write 256? Isn't 255 the max value for the color?

Comment: (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) means range from 0-255. Reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: Ahh Thanks. What about "return"? Is that a faster version of "color = 'rgb(' + red + ',' + green + ',' + blue +')';?

Comment: This has nothing to do with performance, this way the code is just easy to read. This approach does not effect your performance at all.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You were fairly close. It is just that you only set the colors randomly once. If you move the generation of random colors inside of the `changeColor` then you will see the colors change at each interval. Another thing you may want to consider for "continuous" change would be to set the interval to the duration of your animation. It is set to 3000 right now, which is 3 seconds, and your animation is set to 0.7s. So, using 700 (0.7s) in the interval will make it continuous.

```js
var colorChanger = document.getElementById("colour-changer");
var r = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
var g = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
var b = Math.round(Math.random()*255);

function changeColor(){
    r = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
    g = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
    b = Math.round(Math.random()*255);

  colorChanger.style.backgroundColor =  "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";

}

var myTimer = setInterval(changeColor, 700);
var running = true;

colorChanger.onclick = function(){

  if(running) {
    clearInterval(myTimer);
    colorChanger.innerHTML = "Timer stopped";
    running = false;
  } else {
    myTimer = setInterval(changeColor, 700);
    colorChanger.innerHTML = "";
    running = true;
  }
 
};
```

```css
#colour-changer {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  margin:30px auto;
  background-color:#fff;

  -webkit-transition:background-color 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.7s;
  transition:background-color 0.7s;
}
```

```html
  <div id="colour-changer"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for for both editing my question and suggesting to change the timing!